# Trouble with horizontal frequency histogram

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, histogram

Am having many problems with coding C. Apologies for any bad mistakes. Im trying to do simple horizontal histogram for frequency of integers in array. No matter what it prints out incorrect and makes infinite loop. I believe the problem lies in printHistogram function. Any tips?

Here is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Prints histogram to screen using horizontal bar chart
void printHistogram ( int *hist, int n );

int main ( void )
{
    int i, n;

    printf ("How many values for array? ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    int list[n];
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("Enter value: ");
        scanf ("%d", &list[i]);
    }

    // Process data to compute histogram
    int hist[10];    


    // Print histogram
    printHistogram ( hist, 10);

    return 0;
}

void printHistogram ( int *list, int n )
{
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("[%d] ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < list[i]; j++)
            printf ("*");
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
 for (j = 0; j < list[i]; j++)
```

when, you're trying to use `list[i]`, but based on the argument passed, the value is indeterminate. So, in this case, this invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and the loop goes haywire.

To elaborate, you have defined `int hist[10];` as a local variable and did not initialize it, so all the members contain indeterminate value. You then, go ahead and pass the array to `printHistogram()`, inside which, you receive it via `list` and then, dereference that and expect to get some valid value magically, which is not possible.

OTOH, you are scanning values in `list` inside the `main()` and not using it. You need to make some corrections so as to make use of the scanned value later, which seems to be the actual target.

Comment: So, how do I initalize hist array? It's user input so I cant see how to do that?

Comment: @BoloShmolo What is the problem with passing `list` and `n` themselves?

Comment: I want to make sure that the histogram only goes to 10 so I made the hist array. Is what you say possible?

Comment: @BoloShmolo OK then, after scanning `n`, keep a check. Otherwise, you can use a certain range of resolution, but that depends.

Comment: check as in if statement?

Comment: @BoloShmolo Yeah, why not?